# Mutable borrow in previous iteration, or maybe a lifetime issue?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I've got code that will not compile, and I do not understand why. Here is a simplified, contrived version of it:

```
struct Thing<'a> {
    slice: &'a [u8],
}

struct ThingGetter {
    buffer: [u8; 10],
    index: usize,
}

impl ThingGetter {
    pub fn next_thing(&mut self) -> Option<Thing> {
        self.index += 1;
        if self.index == 42 {
            return None;
        } else {
            let thing = Thing {
                slice: &self.buffer[..],
            };
            return Some(thing);
        }
    }
}

struct Wrapper {
    getter: ThingGetter,
}

impl Wrapper {
    pub fn get_thing(&mut self) -> Option<Thing> {
        loop {
            if let Some(thing) = self.getter.next_thing() {
                return Some(thing);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It fails with:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.getter` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/thing.rs:31:34
   |
29 |     pub fn get_thing(&mut self) -> Option<Thing> {
   |                      - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
30 |         loop {
31 |             if let Some(thing) = self.getter.next_thing() {
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `self.getter` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
32 |                 return Some(thing);
   |                        ----------- returning this value requires that `self.getter` is borrowed for `'1`
```

I have slogged through a ton of Stack Overflow answers pertaining to multiple mutable borrows and to lifetimes, but I'm just not seeing the answer.

If the `continue;` line is changed to `return None;` it compiles fine.

I understand that `thing` depends on `getter`, which is borrowed mutably. What I don't see is why this code thinks that `getter` is getting borrowed twice, once in the previous iteration. The borrow from the previous iteration is no longer accessible once you call `if let Some(thing) = ...` again.

Or maybe this is a lifetime issue? I can't tell from the compiler message.

[Here's a link to the playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea7ffcc2c9d12498257ad8732e80440e)

Comment: This is a known limitation of the borrow checker and [fixed by](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/rjsGjYe3x) [polonius](https://github.com/rust-lang/polonius)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite certain you encountered the largest known false positive of the current borrow checker.

The new experimental borrow checker, called `polonius`, successfully confirms the validity of your code. It isn't stable yet, though.

```bash
RUSTFLAGS="-Zpolonius" cargo +nightly build
```

There are many similar examples for it, but it all boils down to the problem described [here](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/0.3.1/polonius_the_crab/).

In most cases, it's possible to work around this problem. In some rare cases, however, it isn't possible to solve this properly without `unsafe` code. Luckily, the [`polonius-the-crab`](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/0.3.1/polonius_the_crab/) crate provides a sound encapsulation for this small `unsafe` code. With its help, your problem could be solved like this:

```rust
use ::polonius_the_crab::prelude::*;

struct Thing<'a> {
    slice: &'a [u8],
}

struct ThingGetter {
    buffer: [u8; 10],
    index: usize,
}

impl ThingGetter {
    pub fn next_thing(&mut self) -> Option<Thing> {
        self.index += 1;
        if self.index == 42 {
            return None;
        } else {
            let thing = Thing {
                slice: &self.buffer[..],
            };
            return Some(thing);
        }
    }
}

struct Wrapper {
    getter: ThingGetter,
}

impl Wrapper {
    pub fn get_thing(&mut self) -> Option<Thing> {
        let mut this = self;
        polonius_loop!(|this| -> Option<Thing<'polonius>> {
            if let Some(thing) = this.getter.next_thing() {
                polonius_return!(Some(thing));
            } else {
                polonius_continue!();
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make my code work using unsafe {}?

Comment: Replying to myself: Nope, apparently not, per the polonius-the-crab link.

Comment: @ccleve Sure there is, but the question is if the result will be [sound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html). Using `polonius-the-crab` gives you the compiler guarantee that it will be sound.